# How do i iterate through a collection?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to list all members of a discord server that have a certain role.
I can isolate them from the others, and I can `console.log` them as one collection.
but when it comes to iterating through that collection to get individual properties such as their username, I tried everything and I have no clue of how to access them one by one like I would do with a regular array by its index.
I do not want to `console.log` them, but to access to their individual properties, like `members[9].user.username`

I tried every kind of for loop.

```
let membersWithRole = roles.find(role => role.name === role_name).members;
for (var i in membersWithRole)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

I expect to be able to iterate through a collection, whatever that is (I've searched for that too, can't find a proper and simple definition of what that is)

Comment: did you try `console.log(membersWithRole[i])` ?

Comment: @Taki `i` is **no**t an index

Comment: yes i tried with a regular index for loop like i would do with an array, but that did'nt work either

Comment: here i is supposed to be an object, the current member, but no, i is nothing, it don't even enter the loop, or any kind of loop i tried

Comment: Is there an error? It sounds like `roles.find(...)` isn't finding the role and returning `undefined`. Trying to read the `members` property would then throw *"Cannot read property `members` of undefined."* Also, see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) for the Discord.js documentation on Collections. Note that it extends the Map prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've found out that the loop I was looking for was "forEach", shown as follows:

```
let membersWithRole = roles.find(role => role.name === role_name).members;
membersWithRole.forEach(member => {
    //I can do what I want with member here.
});
```

And it works just fine.